# The image URL that was uploaded is not getting stored in Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, vite

I am encountering an issue with my React website where the image URL from Firebase Storage is not displaying as expected. I have followed the Firebase documentation and have implemented the code to retrieve and display the image URL, but it seems like something is not working correctly.

Here's what I have done:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { firestore } from "./firebase";
import { collection, addDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { imageDb } from "./firebase";
import { v4 } from "uuid";
import { getDownloadURL, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";

function servicesInput() {
 // State variables for form inputs
const [newName, setNewName] = useState("");
const [newSkills, setNewSkills] = useState("");
const [newLocation, setNewLocation] = useState("");
const [newdescrip, setNewDescrip] = useState("");
const [newEmailUrl, setNewEmailUrl] = useState("");
const [newWhatsappLink, setNewWhatsappLink] = useState("");
const [myImg, setMyImg] = useState("");

// Function to handle image upload
const handleUpload = (e) => {
// console.log(e.target.files[0]);
const imgs = ref(imageDb, `Imgs/${v4()}`);
uploadBytes(imgs, e.target.files[0]).then((data) => {
  console.log(data, "imgs");
  getDownloadURL(data.ref).then((val) => {
    setMyImg(val);
       });
     });
   };

   // Firestore collection reference
   const jobscollectionRef = collection(firestore, "jobs");

   // Function to submit a new job
   const onSubmitNewJob = async () => {
    try {
      await addDoc(jobscollectionRef, {
    yourName: newName,
    skills: newSkills,
    location: newLocation,
    descrip: newdescrip,
    emailUrl: newEmailUrl,
    whatsappLink: newWhatsappLink,
    imgUrl: myImg,
    });
   } catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
   }
 };
```

Comment: It's not clear what problem you have, can you explain what is the expected behavior and what you have instead? ALso share if you have any errors in the console. You can also add a console log for `myImg` and tell what you have and what you expect instead.

Comment: Welcome to SO. One way to catch errors before posting question is do some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected. The include those findings in your question -  what line went wrong, was there an error or unexpected result in a var or code flow?